# Description of the algorithm for sorting ASCII characters alphabetically

Tags: algorithm, sorting, character, ascii

I am a beginner web developer and as a test task I got the following:

> An unordered array of printed ASCII characters is given. Describe in your own words (without code or pseudocode) a sorting algorithm that allows you to sort this array alphabetically in linear time. It is necessary to describe the actions at each step of the algorithm. Is a stable version of such a sorting algorithm possible?

I'm not very good at algorithms, because I have just started studying, so I do not understand how to approach this task.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

> printed ASCII characters

I suppose they mean [*printable* ASCII characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters), which are characters with ASCII code in the range 32-126, so 95 characters.

> Describe in your own words

For each relevant ASCII code, count how many times that character occurs in the input. The idea is that you do this in one pass over the input: for each encountered character increment the relevant counter.

Iterate the above (95) counters in order of ASCII code, and output that many times the corresponding character. So if the counter is zero, don't output the character, if it the counter is 3, output that character three times.

> Is a stable version of such a sorting algorithm possible?

Yes. This is only relevant when each character in the input is accompanied by some related data (payload). In that case we should not only maintain a counter per ASCII code, but collect the associated payloads in an array that is associated with that ASCII code.

For more information, see [Counting Sort on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

Answer (score 0):

To do this, sorting is used by counting:

0. Create an array based on the length of the input array to record the number of numbers encountered in the indexes, and write the numbers themselves to the values standing on these indexes.
1. In one pass, for each corresponding number (ASCII code), count how many characters occur at the input.
2. If the number occurs more than once, the counter increments the number of times by one.
3. Print the ASCII letter codes in the ranges from 65 to 90 and 97 to 122 as many times as it was counted once

Yes, a stable variant of such a sorting algorithm is possible, because elements with the same value are in the output array in the same order as in the input